# Pyti rsi produces negative numbers

Tags: python

Pyti relative strength index produces negative numbers when it is supposed to be between 0 and 100.

```
from pyti.relative_strength_index import relative_strength_index as rsi
import numpy as np

y=[1,3,5,2,6,2,8,5,5,6,7,1,78,3,7,3,67,3,563,4545,563,2,65,3,56,34,56,43,56,56,56,562343243,43,43,45,56,2,2356,4345,2,67,34,6,3,56,2343,56,45,56,67,56,67,23,4556,23,45,3,56,56,45,6767,1]
s= np.array(y)
rsssi = rsi(s,3)
print(rsssi)
```

Comment: Please add some context to your question, like explaining what your expected result is and maybe some example output of your current code.

Comment: The relative strength indicator must produce a number between 0 and 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug inside `pyti`:

```
gains =  [0 if filtered_gain[idx] is True else changes[idx] for idx in range(0, len(filtered_gain))]
                                      ^
                     Here -------------
                                      V
losses = [0 if filtered_loss[idx] is True else abs(changes[idx]) for idx in range(0, len(filtered_loss))]
```

that causes `gains` and `losses` to ignore real gains/losses. In addition, if you will take into consideration that the last commit in this library was a year ago, you will understand that there is a very small chance this bug will be fixed.

I recommend you to copy-paste [this](https://github.com/kylejusticemagnuson/pyti/blob/master/pyti/relative_strength_index.py) code to your project and change these lines:

```
gains =  [0 if filtered_gain[idx] is True else changes[idx] for idx in range(0, len(filtered_gain))]

losses = [0 if filtered_loss[idx] is True else abs(changes[idx]) for idx in range(0, len(filtered_loss))]
```

to these:

```
gains =  [0 if filtered_gain[idx] else changes[idx] for idx in range(0, len(filtered_gain))]

losses = [0 if filtered_loss[idx] else abs(changes[idx]) for idx in range(0, len(filtered_loss))]
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will accept it.